# Tableau create unique max date

Tags: tableau-api

I Need to get the Unique value of Max([Date]).

I have this calculation for max date:

```
{ FIXED [City] : Max([Date]) }
```

Count :

```
IF[Max Date (Last Street)]= [Date] 
THEN [Count Record]
Else 0
END
```

For Example:

```
City    Date              Street        I get (Count)        I Want (Count)
Miami   01/01/2019        1st            0                    0
Miami   01/02/2019        2nd            0                    0
Miami   01/03/2019        3rd            1                    0
Miami   01/03/2019        4th            1                    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good situation to mix LOD calculations and Table Calculations. Your initial LOD function looks good, as it will find the complete max date per each city. From there, you can apply the concept of the calculated field you already have started and add a Table Calculation (Last()):

```
IF ATTR([Max Date (Last Street)]) = ATTR([Date]) 
    AND LAST() == 0
THEN [Count Record]
Else 0
END
```

Note that the other portions of the calculated field are wrapped in ATTR() to make them into aggregations.

Once you add additional cities back into the data, you'll have to edit the table calculation by `Right clicking on table calculation on view > Edit Table Calculation...`

[image]

Take note of the fact that **Specific Dimensions** is selected and **Restarting Every** is changed to "City"

Final product should look like this:

[image]

**Alternative Method:**

If you'd like to purely use LODs and your street names always contain *unique ascending numbers*:

```
If Date = {Fixed [City]: MAX(Date)} 
    AND REGEXP_EXTRACT([Street],'(\d+)') = {FIXED [City], [Date]: 
        MAX(REGEXP_EXTRACT([Street],'(\d+)'))}
Then 1
Else 0
END
```

The above will essentially extract the number from the street then add it as a condition in addition to the MAX(Date) which already exists. Then the you will only get a 1 when both conditions have been met.

The end result will be the same as above.

Comment: The Grand Totals will show on the Alternative/LOD version. Grand Totals don't work well with Table Calculations.

Comment: Eventually I have to remove all fields and only leave the grand total on my dashboard. any suggestion?

Comment: The alternative/LOD version should work for this as well. Just drag everything off of the view except [City] (which I assume you want to keep). The final result will show the hopefully correct count of the Count(Max(Date)) next to the City. Even removing city works - it will give you the total of all cities combined. In this case its just a matter of ensuring that the formula matches the data (especially the format of street) - the general idea behind the calculated field, though, is what's important.

Comment: Edited Alternative/LOD portion of my answer to add `[Date]` to `[Fixed]` portion of LOD, as you will want the the max of both in that condition.